# Where did all the questions come from?

Tags: discussion

It appears the beta was seeded with existing questions. Where are they from, the existing Stack Exchange money site?

Comment: Possibly merged with another community?  How old is the previous community?

Comment: The previous community was about 10 months old.

Comment: Heh I just asked the same question on meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59672/questions-on-beta-sites-are-way-older-than-they-should-be

Comment: Yes, the site was seeded with questions from the StackExchange 1.0 site I founded, BasicallyMoney.com.  User accounts appear to be intact as well, which is sweet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They were migrated from the existing BasicallyMoney site apparently. All of my questions and rep from that site appear to have transferred over.

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Saved a ton of copy and paste.  Did they do this on the math site or any other?

Comment: BasicallyMoney.com is the first site to undergo such a **SE 1.0** to **SE 2.0** migration.