# How are there questions asked in March when the site was only proposed on Area 51 in June?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did all the questions come from?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-the-questions-come-from)

I just came across [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/) which appears with a date of "Mar 29", but how is this possible when the Personal Finance site was [proposed on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721?phase=definition) only two months ago (June)?